# Why are linux's IPv4 address taking 16 bytes instead of 4

Tags: c++, linux, dns, ip

I'm trying to resolve a domain name to an ipv4 address.

Here's a minimal code of what I'm doing

```
addrinfo hints, *results;
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
int error = getaddrinfo("google.com", 0, &hints, &results);
for(addrinfo* info = results; info; info = info->ai_next)
{
    std::cout << (info->ai_family == AF_INET6 ? "ip6" : "ip4")
              << '[' << info->ai_addrlen << "]: ";
    for(uint i = 0; i < info->ai_addrlen; ++i)
        std::cout << int(((uint8_t*)info->ai_addr)[i]) << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
freeaddrinfo(results);
```

When I run this, it prints:

```
ip4[16]: 2 0 0 0 216 58 208 238 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
ip4[16]: 2 0 0 0 216 58 208 238 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
ip4[16]: 2 0 0 0 216 58 208 238 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The actual ip of google.com is `216.58.208.238`. So for some reason, for ip v4, ai_addr contains 16 bytes and actually stores the address at bytes 4 to 8.

My question is: **what are the 12 other bytes for ?**

I read [the docs](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo), and googled a bit but found nothing on `addr_len`. Also note that I didn't set the `AI_V4MAPPED` flag.

Comment: I think it is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608707/why-is-zero-padding-needed-in-sockaddr-in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this is actually *required* by some standard, but `struct sockaddr` is defined to contain a `short` for the address family and then 14 bytes of address-family-specific data.

Every type used as an address must be compatible with that, thus, be at least the same length.

For `struct sockaddr_in` (the one for IPv4), it looks like this:

```
struct sockaddr_in {
    short            sin_family;
    unsigned short   sin_port;
    struct in_addr   sin_addr;
    char             sin_zero[8];
};
```

2 bytes for the address family, 2 bytes for the port, 4 bytes for the IPv4 address and 8 bytes of padding to reach the length of `struct sockaddr`.

That said: Your question is *slightly* wrong, this is not an IPv4 address (that would be just `struct in_addr` which is indeed just 4 bytes) but a socket address for IPv4. Still, 8 bytes are "wasted" here.

Comment: POSIX defines the `sa_family` and `sa_data` fields as required in `struct sockaddr`, but only specifies that `sa_data` is a variable-length field (i.e. a flexible array in C99 jargon). So it's not required that `sa_data` has 14 bytes, but Linux chose to do it that way. FreeBSD does the same thing, but it adds an additional `sa_len` field at the beginning of `struct sockaddr`.

Comment: Good comment, that's what I *suspected*. So the "Why" is still a valid question that should be addressed to whoever designed `struct sockaddr` for Linux first.